# insert in Mysql innodb table extremely slow

Tags: mysql, innodb, mariadb, myisam

I can get 2 million inserts per minute on myisam table, but only 3000 insert per minute if I change to innodb

```
CREATE TABLE myisam_table ( c1 int default NULL, c2 varchar(30) default NULL, c3 date default NULL) engine=myisam;
CREATE TABLE innodb_table ( c1 int default NULL, c2 varchar(30) default NULL, c3 date default NULL) engine=innodb;

CREATE PROCEDURE load_myisam_table()  
       begin  
    declare v int default 0;  
    while v < 10000000  
    do  
        insert into myisam_table  
        values (v,'testing','2017-01-01');  
         set v = v + 1;  
    end while;  
    end  


CREATE PROCEDURE load_innodb_table()  
       begin  
    declare v int default 0;  
    while v < 10000000  
    do  
        insert into innodb_table  
        values (v,'testing','2017-01-01');  
         set v = v + 1;  
    end while;  
    end
```

And result:

```
mysql -e "select count(*) from asdf.innodb_table;" ; sleep 60;mysql -e "select count(*) from asdf.innodb_table;" ;
+----------+
| count(*) |
+----------+
|      125 |
+----------+
+----------+
| count(*) |
+----------+
|     2975 |
+----------+
mysql -e "select count(*) from asdf.myisam_table;" ; sleep 60;mysql -e "select count(*) from asdf.myisam_table;" ;
+----------+                                                                                     
| count(*) |                                                                                     
+----------+
|   134446 |
+----------+
+----------+
| count(*) |
+----------+
|  2225277 |
+----------+
```

Comment: Disable query log if enabled and see https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9819271/why-is-mysql-innodb-insert-so-slow/44230232#44230232.  `innodb-flush-log-at-trx-commit=0` and
`sync_binlog=0` will make insert substantially faster.

Comment: You can get a lot more speed (both InnoDB and MyISAM) if you "batch" the inserts.  I suggest 1000 rows per `INSERT` statement.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Running insert/update queries on an *InnoDB* table is significantly slower when no transaction is started. I've run the procedures you listed and the result was that `load_innodb_table` was actually faster than `load_myisam_table`. 
Running `load_innodb_table` with 10m inserts actually means that you're running 10m transactions, as every insert implicitly starts a transaction.

Comment: how do you did that?

Comment: Start a transaction (`BEGIN`) and call the procedure (`CALL load_innodb_table`). Obviously in the same MySQL session.